# Is there a neutral term for "politically correct"?

Tags: phrase-requests, euphemisms

Although no one disagrees with making speech impartial and not offensive, some people think that the process of "Political Correctness" has been carried too far, so the phrase is sometimes considered offensive or derogatory. Is there a better way of saying: "worded so as not to offend anyone"?

Comment: Adding an example sentence of how you'd like to use the term will be important for getting this reopened.

Comment: I don't think that any single term can successfully replace the array of dissimilar meanings that different people have in mind when they use the wording _politically correct_. If you're just trying to find a new wording to convey Merriam-Webster's old definition—which is "conforming to a belief that language and practices which could offend political sensibilities (as in matters of sex or race) should be eliminated"—you might use "race- and gender-neutral [language and practices]." But most people today don't use _politically correct_ in that way, and I believe most of them never did.

Answer (score 2):

*Inoffensive* and *diplomatic* come to mind.  But there's whole page in the [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/politically+correct) to choose from.

Comment: What if 'inoffensive' as a euphemism eventually caused people to bristle? :-)